# PHP сохранить в БД через цикл!

Tags: php, foreach, for

очень нубовский вопрос, извините за это, но прошу помощи.

У меня есть некоторое количество массивов по сути одинаковые, но содержащие разные значения (например):

```html
  $arr1 = [
    0 => 'Фамилия1',
    1 => 'Имя1',
    2 => 'Отчество1'
    ];
  
  $arr2 = [
    0 => 'Фамилия2',
    1 => 'Имя2',
    2 => 'Отчество2'
    ];
  
// и так далее, до 5ти максимум;
```

И имеется таблица в базе данных (водители), содержащая поля (Фамилия, имя, отчество).

Как правильно запустить цикл, чтоб сохранить этих водителей в ней.

Еще раз извините за такой Basic. Спасибо за помощь заранее.

Comment: `insert` запрос позволяет вставлять несколько строк одновременно. так что ваша задача - сформировать такой запрос и единожды выполнить.

Comment: *У меня есть некоторое количество массивов* Лучше бы это был массив массивов. Его итерать легче.

Answer (score -1):

```
$conn1 = new mysqli('ip', 'root', 'p', 't');


// Check connection
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 

  //Если переменная Name передана


  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn1, "INSERT INTO `voditeli` (fio, name, soname) VALUES (".$value[0].",".$value[1].",".$value[2].")");
    //Если вставка прошла успешно
   if ($sql) {
     echo '<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>';
    } else {

      echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($conn1) . '</p>';
    }

}
```

Comment: минус вам. циклический одинаковый запрос с разными данными - идеальный кандидат для использования подготовленных запросов, так что это будет и эффективней с точки зрения производительности, и безопасно с точки зрения подстановки данных

Comment: да это понятно, он же только учится, поэтому примерно и показал

Comment: https://htmler.ru/2014/08/11/zashhita-ot-sql-inektsiy-na-php/